# nmap retry option to scan list of IPs

Tags: ping, nmap

I'm trying to scan list of IP addresses  using below command

```
nmap -v -n  -sP -iL <IP-list-file.txt>
```

here I'm looking retry option with nmap command for the failed probe retransmission. Above command will do a single ICMP probe for each IP/hosts. Even I tried with --max-retries  no result. So I'm looking a similiar option like { ping -c<2> IP > along with this nmap.

Even tried "-A -T5" no result

Note:- My purpose is to check only whether the host/IP is alive or dead that's it. Preferably nmap utility.

Answer (score 0):

Nmap uses a lot of different methods for [host discovery](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html). The options that you used will do one of two things depending on whether you have root privileges:

1. If you **do** run Nmap as root, it will send four probes: ICMP Echo Request, TCP SYN to port 443, TCP ACK to port 80, and ICMP Timestamp Request. Only if all four fail to get a response will it mark the target as down.
2. If you **do not** run Nmap as root, it will attempt to make a TCP connection to port 80 and port 443. If both of these time out, it will mark the target as down.

So this method is already more robust than simply using `/bin/ping`. Nmap also retries probes a certain number of times depending on how reliable the network seems. For host discovery, this starts out at 2 retransmits per probe. There doesn't really seem to be a way to increase this without Nmap detecting network problems, so the best way to increase confidence in a "down" determination is to add more host discovery probes using the various `-P*` options.

The `-A` and `-T5` options will not help at all. `-A` turns on extra features, none of which will run if the target is considered down, and `-T5` simply tells Nmap to assume a very fast and reliable network. It will never retransmit more than 2 times, and will time out probes very quickly. This is almost certainly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yeah I don't have root privileges, so need to stick on unprivilege user. I tried as a combination of -P* option along with -sP on many scenrio as root user on a test machine as it works fine....

Comment: I want to tell one issue, might be that could be bug with nmap component / command usage problem .I'm using RHEL 5 ,What I found in my investigation was, lets say one IP/host which is discovering in root and not in non-root user , even I can able to ping to that host from non-root user. Even I tried with multiple combination -P* no luck . I also understood , for non-root as host discovery based on 80 & 443, but checked with 10 IPs and discovered 8, none of the discoverd hosts who  doesn't listened on 80/443 port then how the host discovery happens here ? #nmap -v -n  -sP  -iL <iplist> .....

Comment: @user183980 `/bin/ping` is "setuid root," which means that it always runs as root without password. This is necessary to send ICMP. Nmap is not safe to make setuid, so it requires root password before it can send ICMP. Host discovery with TCP (as non-root) can work even if the target ports are closed, because a closed port *resets* the connection; it does not *time out*.